# Use DNS with IIS Express Under Windows XP

Tags: iis, ssl, acl, netsh, httpcfg.exe

I'm setting up VS2010 SP1 with IIS 7.5 Express so I can use SSL in my Dev environment.

Following Scott Hanselman's excellent post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) is working for me. The only problem is he's running on Windows 7 (I assume), where I'm on XP.

The bit that trips me up is where he makes a URL reservation:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://hanselman-w500:80/ user=everyone
```

This isn't working on XP. After some googling, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) and worked out that I need to use the 'httpcfg' utility instead, general syntax:

```
httpcfg set urlacl /u {http://URL:Port/ | https://URL:Port/} /a ACL
```

However there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of the 'user=' switch and I'm not expert enough with the ACL descriptor language to be able to work out the equivalent.

Can anyone give me the equivalent command using httpcfg, or is the equivalent not possible under XP ?

Edit: at the bottom of the Hanselman post there is a command line helper method which does the job

```
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupFriendlyHostnameUrl -url:http://hanselman-w500:80/
```

However I was hoping to use the full step by step process, so the question stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link looks like what the Hanselman post was based on. It has both netsh and httpcfg forms of the commands.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1005/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express/